# Symfony does not return Arraycollection(one to many)

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with an empty ArrayCollection.
With one-to-many and many-to-one relationships

This is Brand entity:

```
class Brand
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var Model[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Model", mappedBy="brand")
     */
    private $models;

    /**
     * Brand constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->models= new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Model[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getModels()
    {
        return $this->models;
    }

    /**
     * @param Model $model
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addModel(Model $model)
    {
        $this->models[] = $model;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

And this is the Model entity:

```
class Model
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="modelName", type="string", length=60)
     */
    private $modelName;

    /**
     * @var Brand
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Brand", inversedBy="models")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $brand;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set modelName
     *
     * @param string $modelName
     *
     * @return Model
     */
    public function setModelName($modelName)
    {
        $this->modelName = $modelName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get modelName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getModelName()
    {
        return $this->modelName;
    }

    /**
     * @param Brand $brand
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBrand(Brand $brand)
    {
        $this->brand= $brand;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Brand
     */
    public function getBrand()
    {
        return $this->brand;
    }
}
```

And Controller:

```
$UserRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Brand::class);
        $all = $UserRepo->find($brandId);
```

Symfony does not return any error.
However, it only downloads the brandName corresponding to $ brandId. Unfortunately, the ArrayCollection is empty.
Can someone tell me where I made a mistake :(

Comment: Doctrine will lazy load associations when needed. So if you try to output data (ie in twig) it will do the necessary queries to fetch the data you need. If you want to avoid this (it can generate a lot of queries) you should create a custom repository with your own methods where you join in the associations you want available. They will then be loaded with the first query results

Comment: Ok, it worked. I have add in Brand entity fields cascade and fetch, for @ORM\OneToMany: cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER"